# Copy sheet from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need to take (copy) sheet from one workbook and append it to the end of existing excel document. I wrote this code but it doesnt work and gives an error. Please help =)

```
Public wb As Workbook 'workbook with the source sheet
Sub test()
    dim wbNew as workbook 'destination workbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(Me.fileDestPathTextBox.Value)

    wbNew.Sheets.Add After:=wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count).Name = Me.sheetNameTextBox.Value
    wb.Sheets("Souce Sheet").Copy wbNew.Sheets(Me.sheetNameTextBox.Value)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't add a sheet and then try and copy your sheet to that sheet - you just copy the original sheet to the target workbook:

```
Sub test()
    dim wbNew as workbook 'destination workbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(Me.fileDestPathTextBox.Value)


    wb.Sheets("Souce Sheet").Copy After:=wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the target workbook protected, or a different format (e.g. xls versus xlsx)?

Comment: i think its different format...do you think its causing an issue?